# Differences between behavior delegation approaches

Tags: javascript

Could anyone explain differences between the following ways of composing objects in Javascript (ES6+)? Why and when should one be used over the other? I'd like to know arguments in favor and/or against each approach.

```
'use strict';
const foo = {
  say() {
    console.log('I say', this.message);
  }
};

const bar = {
  message: 'Hoo!'
};

// Method 1
const baz = Object.assign({}, foo, bar);
baz.say();

// Method 2
const baz2 = Object.assign(Object.create(foo), bar);
baz2.say();

// Method 3
const baz3 = Object.create(foo);
baz3.message = 'Heey!';
baz3.say();

// Method 4
Object.setPrototypeOf(bar, foo);
bar.say();

// Prints out:
// I say Hoo!
// I say Hoo!
// I say Heey!
// I say Hoo!
```

Comment: 2 and 3 produce the same result. The others all produce slightly different results, so it depends on what exactly you want to achieve. It seems like you may want to read up on prototypes first to learn exactly what they are: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/b42f036a366f3ee1f7b4eae07e74ac9cc8d20daf/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/README.md .

Comment: While almost no JS developer knows his prototypes, I am well aware of what they are. You said "it depends on what exactly you want to achieve" and that is exactly what I'm looking for: when to use one over the other. I agree YDKJS is a great series, by the way.

Comment: But then it basically boils down to: Do you need the features that prototype inheritance provide? If yes, then you have to use it. If not, it doesn't really matter. That's the technical aspect. You can also look at it from a semantic point of view: *Is* `bar` *a* `foo`? If yes choose inheritance. If not, don't use inheritance. I imagine the arguments are similar to ones used when discussing composition (or mixins / traits) vs inheritance. Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to try and take a shot at answering my own question, after some research.

All of the above approaches exemplify ways of implementing *composition* in Javascript.

**Method 1** uses `Object.assign()` to create a type of *cloning* or *concatenated* prototype, often referred to as a *mixin*. No classical prototypal inheritance takes place.

> Useful for handling **state data** or providing **default values**.

On **method 2**, `Object.create()` generates a delegate prototype which gets extended with additional properties after `Object.assign()`. Here, the resulting object's prototype points to `foo`.

> Good for **sharing functionality** and **methods** between objects.

As [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) correctly pointed out, **method 3** is essentially the same as its predecessor.

`Object.setPrototypeOf()` on **method 4** acts pretty much as `Object.create()` here, but instead of creating a *new object*, it changes the linkage of an existing `bar` object.

On this topic, "open source" book series [You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch5.md) expresses:

> Ignoring the slight performance disadvantage (throwing away an object that's later garbage collected) of the `Object.create(..)` approach, it's a little bit shorter and may be perhaps a little easier to read than the ES6+ approach. But it's probably a syntactic wash either way.

For a more in depth analysis of this points, [this 2013 talk by Eric Elliot](https://vimeo.com/69255635) goes a long way. [His medium](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/) might also prove a good source.